# Configure a network card on public IP and Wifi usb dongle on LAN

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, configuration, internet-connection

I have an Ubuntu Server running on 12.04.1 LTS with the GUI installed too. My server has an internal gigabit ethernet card which is configured to serve a web app on a Public IP. At this point I did not have any issues. The web app loads perfectly from any computer in the web. I do have the problem that I cant access the internet from the server itself, I open the web browser and does not load, but yet the server is accessible from the web, maybe this is a configuration from my ISP, Ive been looking for an explanation but still havent found one. Maybe here I cant get an appropiate answer.

Anyways, thats not the real problem. The problem is that I need to load a lot of data to the webapp, and I would like to do it locally through the LAN. So I installed a Wifi usb dongle. It worked perfectly, now I can get internet on the Server and access it locally. But now my public ip wont load the webapp.

The USB dongle is connected to a Wireless Router which has access to the internet. My ethernet card is connected to a switch provided by my ISP where I connect my other servers to get a Public IP. They gave me the range of IPś and told me I just had to configure my server with the public ip I wanted and leave it static, and it worked fine until y installed the USB dongle.

Here is my configuration on `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 190.109.197.---
netmask 255.255.255.---
gateway 190.109.197.---
```

I would appreciate your help so much.

Comment: What is in your `/etc/resolv.conf`? Can you rresolve network names (`host askubuntu.com`)? can you ping your gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Right below 'gateway' add a new line:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 190.109.197.<suffix of gateway>
```

Restart eth0 and you should be able to connect:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
ping -c3 www.google.com
```